# Jquery mobile Link clicked twice the page disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the problem that when I click a navigation link it shows the page as it should. But if I click on the link again it loses all of its contents.

Is there someone who knows how I solve this?

I use jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js

```
    <div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="red btn"><a class="tildig" href="#tildig" data-transition="fade" >
      <p>TIL DIG</p>
      </a></li>
    <li class="blue btn"><a class="kontakt" href="#kontakt"data-transition="fade" >
      <p>KONTAKT / BOOKM&Oslash;DE</p>
      </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Start of page -->

<div data-role="page" id="tildig">
  <div data-role="header" data-nobackbtn="true"> </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>Dette er siden TIL DIG<br>
      Jeg er nummer 3</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer"> </div>
</div>

<!-- End of page -->

<!-- Start of page -->

<div data-role="page" id="kontakt">
  <div data-role="header" data-nobackbtn="true"> </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>Dette er siden KONTAKT / BOOKM&Oslash;DE</p>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer"> </div>
</div>

<!-- End of page -->
```

Java

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js

Comment: Kasperrrrrrr! We're not magicians (although some might be)!!!! :D More information is needed. A code snippet or something would be helpful! :D

Comment: Kasperrrrrrr! Where's the JavaScript? :D

Comment: jQm beta 2 requires jQuery version 1.6.2

Comment: I have changed it now, but it does not help .. However, I found out that it is only on the Iphone make the mistake

Answer (score 2):

I think i know what your problem is - at least I had some very similar stuff where a listview kept dissapearing - had to do with jqm caching.

```
<div data-role="page" id="book_index" data-dom-cache="true">
```

This attribute made the page reappear, hope it helps